# When cron file will execute if crontab has schdule earlier then server cron

Tags: magento2

To set the magento cron we need to add following commands in crontab file on server.

```
*/10 * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run 
*/10* * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php
*/10 * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

and we can create the custom cron with crontab.xml

```
<group id="default">
    <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Magento\SampleMinimal\Cron\Test" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/5 * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

As you can see default magento cron is set for every 10 minutes and magento custom cron is set every 5 minutes.
So my question is custom cron will execute in every 15 minutes or will it execute in every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You must to install magento crontab by command:

> php bin/magento cron:install

In magento 2, cron runs every minute. After install, you will see:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/your_project/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/your_project/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/your_project/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/your_project/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/your_project/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/your_project/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Comment: I think you haven't read the question clearly, I have already set up the cron

Comment: Yes, I have read the question. Your cron configuration is wrong. If you need your task runs every 5 minutes, you need to setup up crontab as "* * * * * *" and not "*/10 * * *". In this way, magento can't execute your task every 5 minutes.